# TouchableOpacity onPress doesn't trigger on iPhone 7 only

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I have a TouchableOpacity and it doesn't trigger the onPress event consistently, when I press the TouchableOpacity. It only triggers after spamming it for a while. The opacity changes and onPressIn and onPressOut functions work. onLongPress doesn't work either. This only seems to happen on iPhone 7. On iPhone 6 it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
const myStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  threshold: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    height: undefined,
    aspectRatio: 0.757,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0
  }
});

class ThresholdIcon extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onThresholdPress = this.onThresholdPress.bind(this);
    this.state = ({
      width: new Animated.Value(12),
      bot: new Animated.Value(0),
    });
  }
  onThresholdPress() {
    const { onPress, type } = this.props;
    onPress(type);
  }
  render() {
    const { type, onPress } = this.props;

    const threshold = getThresholdPercent(type);
    const img = getImg(type);

    return (<Animated.View
      style={{
        bottom: this.state.bot.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: ['-80%', '-55%']
        })
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={this.onThresholdPress}
      >
        <Animated.Image
          style={[myStyles.threshold, {
            left: this.state.width.interpolate({
              inputRange: [12, 20],
              outputRange: ['10%', '20%']
            }),
            width: this.state.width.interpolate({
              inputRange: [12, 20],
              outputRange: ['12%', '20%']
            })
          }]}
          source={img}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Animated.View>);
  }
}
```

I have tried adding zIndex to outermost Animated.View and removing all animations. Neither has worked. Can I just use onPressOut instead of onPress? Is that not basically the same thing?

Comment: I noticed this in something I'm working on now, and it was a TouchableOpacity with <Text /> and it only activated the click when I tapped the area taken up by the Text. This same thing could be happening here.

Comment: In short, the hitspace could be only the child element; put a border on that and see if it highlights any useful data.

Comment: you need to bind the click event to the handler, you can use .bind or simply by using arrow function. like this onPress={() => this.onThresholdPress}

Comment: Ganesh Cauda I have bound the function in constructor.  this.onThresholdPress = this.onThresholdPress.bind(this);

Comment: agm1984 do you mean put a border on the child element? Did you still experience the opacity change when you clicked on the touchable area where Text wasn't taking up area?

Comment: The children seem to take up just the area they are supposed to. I'm not trying to click outside the children of the TouchableOpacity.